# RStudio Pro server + library not loading

Tags: linux, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm not sure if there's a way to make this work in RStudio Pro server (in Centos 7), but the following in regular R loads the library without error(s):

```
% xvfb-run R --no-save
> library(MODIStsp)
>
```

In RStudio Pro server (web version) this happens:

```
> library(MODIStsp)
R session is headless; GTK+ not initialized.

(R:3641): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MODIStsp’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'cairoDevice', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: GDK display not found - please make sure X11 is running
```

Any suggestions or ideas most appreciated!

Comment: Did you run Rstudio using xvfb-run?

Comment: Since Rstudio Pro server is a web-based application, I don't see how xvfb-run can be used.